# Random Diagonal 2D Array Input

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to input words diagonally into a 2d array in C. I was able to do this for words horizontally and vertically, however it's trickier here because the words can be input going upwards or downwards diagonally. I want the variable X to be 0 for the first iteration of the loop, and then either increment for the rest of the loop or decrement for the rest of the loop (whichever one it does to be chosen randomly). Is that possible?

```
            for(i=0, j = 0; i < wordLen && j < arrayHeight; j++, i++)
                    array[arrayRow+X][arrayColumn+i] = wordList[k][j];
```

tl;dr I'm fixated on getting the X variable to do something specific in this manner, and I can't figure out how to do it

Comment: Did you try to randomly decide on a direction, then just iterate `X` accordingly?

Comment: I can't format my reply properly, anyways I planned to do that if I understand correctly but I need X to be 0 for the first iteration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not

```
for(i=0, j = 0; i < wordLength && j < HEIGHT; j++, i++)
    array[arrayRow-i][arrayColumn+i] = animals[k][j];
```

and

```
for(i=0, j = 0; i < wordLength && j < HEIGHT; j++, i++)
    array[arrayRow+j][arrayColumn-i] = animals[k][j];
```

etc. for different directions

or alternatively

```
for(i=0, j = 0; i < wordLength && j < HEIGHT; j++, i++)
    array[arrayRow+wordlength-i-1][arrayColumn+i] = animals[k][j];
```

or if you want to use `x`

```
for(i=0, j = 0; i < wordLength && j < HEIGHT; j++, i++)
 {
    x=wordlength-i-1;
    array[arrayRow+x][arrayColumn+i] = animals[k][j];
 }
```

Comment: oh I somehow hadn't thought of that, I can just randomly choose which for loop I use! thank you!